# json paramter delete and saved as it run

Tags: java, json

Here I have downloaded 100 numbers from the random.org api which prints a json as follows
`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"random":{"data":[14,75,6,32,69,77,16,3,37,37,35,6,23,73,5,12,93,71,32,37,56,59,75,39,48,83,57,70,79,31,16,28,62,45,69,67,81,98,13,71,99,80,79,86,1,48,43,52,42,41,3,44,73,96,13,51,52,26,69,47,35,72,61,51,42,58,9,1,15,92,32,81,33,14,5,66,80,8,5,97,7,79,100,40,36,33,91,65,33,65,63,33,38,27,72,82,44,16,17,51],"completionTime":"2022-12-01 22:21:52Z"},"bitsUsed":664,"bitsLeft":244024,"requestsLeft":991,"advisoryDelay":1710},"id":421}`

What i want to do with the json is to specifically pick a number from the data parameter set like so {"data":14} every time i execute the program which is what i have started on here .

```
  @Path("/getID")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public String getID() {
      
      String numbers = "";
      List <String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("Randoms.json"));
       
         for (String line : lines) {
             
              numbers += line;
         }
      

      return numbers;
```

When the number is chosen I want it to be deleted from the set and to be saved in another json file acting like a unique ID which takes the ID from a dataset like this and deletes it from the original source so it cant be used again like this

`{"ID":(number)}`

So for i have a class where it retrieves the numbers and have it save it to the file and my restful service and prints the output which is the full JSON output as shown at the top.

Comment: Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74648963/edit) the question, clarify what exactly you want to delete (show an example). Also specify which library for parsing JSON (Jackson, Gson, etc.) you're going to use, dialing with JSON manually doesn't make much sense (unless it's a requirement of your assignment).

Comment: Done thanks for letting me know and im currently using Gson

Comment: `[data:14] ` is **not** a valid JSON. That's what you want to save back to the file? You didn't explain why you need to preserve exactly this number. And you didn't tell anything about JSON library you're using. The question remains unclear.

Comment: let me expand on this more one moment

Comment: Sorry about that i elaborated on it more here

Comment: Are you asking how to parse JSON? How to write JSON? How to update a file? Please explain where exactly you're stuck and what you need help with.

Comment: Im asking on how to use the json in order to specifically pick a number from "data" for example when it runs once, it will take the first number which is 14 like this{"ID":14} and then the next number when the program runs again using the next number in the sequence {"ID":75 } and so on basically splitting the numbers from the original json and saving it to another file and delete it from the original file